# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Order" fault in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

When attempting to use req.params.id inside my findById() route I am getting the above message. This has stumped me for a while and I'm sure I'm making a mistake somewhere with my routes/objects. I also tried to use find() or findByIdandUpdate() but it still not working.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBFcs.png]

Comment: First check if you are having the `id` as a value in your controller.
Then check that if it has valid type.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value `req.params.id`. This error occurs mostly when the id which you are passing in model is undefined.

For the best practices validate the id before making the db request.

Please refer to the documentation for express route params.
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Actually, I follow the code on a youtube video for the entire project, everything is fine until this happened. If possible can you watch the video and tell me what I have done wrong? I will very much appreciate that. Thank you!